# Tomcat can't find the JSP file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a issue, my server can't find the jsp file in my project, after the creating server, it gives me a 404 issue, "JSP file not found [/servlet/servlet.jsp]
web.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Servlet.java:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.NEW;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

//@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/servlet.jsp"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet/servlet.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String checkedRadio = req.getParameter("gender");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String universityDomain = "@astanait.edu.kz";
        universityDomain = new StringBuilder(universityDomain).reverse().toString();
        boolean allTrue;
        int check = 1;
        email = new StringBuilder(email).reverse().toString();
        //
        if (email.length() > 16) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                allTrue = email.charAt(i) == universityDomain.charAt(i);
                if (!allTrue) {
                    check = 0;
                }
            }
            if (check != 0) {
                log("37 line");
                log(checkedRadio);
                switch (checkedRadio) {
                    case "female": {
                        resp.setHeader("Location", "https://leadersinheels.com/");
                        log("female");
                        break;
                    }
                    case "male": {
                        resp.getWriter().write("<h2>Kokpar</h2>");
                        resp.getWriter().close();
                        log("male");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                resp.getWriter().println("<html><h2>You need to have a Astana IT University domain</h2></html>");
                resp.getWriter().close();
                log("norm6");
            }
        } else {
            req.setAttribute("submit","You need to have a Astana IT University domain");
            resp.getWriter().println("<html><h2>You need to have a Astana IT University domain</h2></html>");
            resp.getWriter().close();
            log("norm5");
        }
        log("norm4");
    }
}
```

after the creating server it gain a 404 http error, "JSP file [/servlet/servlet.jsp] file not found. Tomcat 9.0.37, creating with war package

servlet.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Titleeeeeeeeeeeee</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()+"/servlet"%>">
    <p><label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" formmethod="post">
    </label>Male</p>
    <p><label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" formmethod="post">
    </label>Female</p><br>
    <label>
        <input type="email" name="email" formmethod="post">
    </label><br>
    <input type="submit" formmethod="post" name="submit">
</form>
<p>something</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I have a configuration issues.

Comment: Where is the `servlet.jsp` file located?

Comment: If the path you delegate to is `/servlet/servlet.jsp` then you'd probably need to have the file `servlet.jsp` in a directory `/servlet` in your WAR.

Comment: @dan1st web->servlet->servlet.jsp

Comment: @KevinBoone where is my WAR located?

Comment: @AbilaikhanZhetes -- I'm afraid I don't know: it was you who mentioned WAR files ;) How are you building this application? With an IDE tool or manually? IDEs generally build WAR files according to the layout of files in your project. If you're using an IDE, and you say which, probably someone can help you. I'm afraid I don't use IDEs a lot, so I'm probably not well-paced to advise.

Comment: @KevinBoone IDE - IntelliJ Idea Ultimate, Student subscription :3, thank you a lot